# Generar digito verificador AFIP y codigo de barras Interleaved 2 of 5 ITF en php

Tags: php

Necesito generar el dígito verificador de un código de barras "Interleaved 2 of 5 ITF" en php, de la siguiente manera: "Se considera para efectuar el cálculo el siguiente ejemplo: 01234567890

- Etapa 1: Comenzar desde la izquierda, sumar todos los caracteres ubicados en las posiciones impares. `0 + 2 + 4 + 6 + 8 + 0 = 20`
- Etapa 2: Multiplicar la suma obtenida en la etapa 1 por el número 3. `20 x 3 = 60`
- Etapa 3:Comenzar desde la izquierda, sumar todos los caracteres que están ubicados en las posiciones pares. `1 + 3 + 5+ 7 + 9 = 25`
- Etapa 4:Sumar los resultados obtenidos en las etapas 2 y 3. `60 + 25 = 85`
- Etapa 5: Buscar el menor número que sumado al resultado obtenido en la etapa 4 dé un número múltiplo de 10. Este será el valor del dígito verificador del módulo 10. `85 + 5 = 90`

De esta manera se llega a que el número 5 es el dígito verificador módulo 10 para el código 01234567890 Siendo el resultado final: 012345678905"

Los datos de CUIT, codigo tipo comprobante, punto de venta, CAI, y fecha de vencimiento están alojados cada uno en una variable.

Por lo tanto mis consultas son 2:

- Primero cómo hago para realizar el cálculo del dígito verificador según la formula matemática expuesta mas arriba.
- Segundo cómo genero el código de barras Interleaved 2 of 5 ITF con los datos expuestos incluido el digito verificador y lo exporto a png.

Desde ya muchas gracias por la paciencia

Comment: ¿que has hecho respecto a esto? ¿puedes compartir tu código que llevas? Además vendría bien en tu pregunta algo de puntos aparte o separar las etapas, como para no leer una línea que no termina nunca. Revisa [ask] para que veas como mejorar tu pregunta. Saludos

Answer (score -1):

Revisá este link
https://groups.google.com/g/afip-php/c/UDrUJDSYwz0/m/dgwEKtA8AgAJ

```
function generateVerifyNumber($string)
  {
    $evens = 0;
    $unevens = 0;
    $string = strrev($string);
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < strlen($string)) {
      if (is_numeric($evens) && is_numeric($unevens) && is_numeric($string)) {
        if ($i % 2 == 0) $unevens += $string[$i];
        else $evens += $string[$i];
        $i++;
      }
    }
    $sum = $evens + ($unevens * 3);
    if (10 - ($sum % 10) == 10) {
      $verify_number = 0;
    } else {
      $verify_number = 10 - ($sum % 10);
    }
    return $verify_number;
  }
```

El código de barras en facil de implementar con este "generador".
https://github.com/picqer/php-barcode-generator

Comment: Los enlaces no son respuestas. Escribe aqui la información relevante.

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el funcionamiento del sitio. Gracias por tomar el tiempo en responder, revisa [answer] para que edites tu pregunta y agregues las partes esenciales en tu respuesta y dejes el enlace como referencia.